# Input username and password for SQL Server from userform VBA Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I want to input username and password SQL Server from userform VBA Excel, but I don't understand how to do that. So I create code like this:

```
Sub OPenCOnn()    
   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
   cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=172.20.20.20;Initial Catalog=bank;User ID=" & txtUser.Text & ";Password=" & txtPass.Text & ";"
End Sub
```

But its didn't work. I receive the below error:

> run time error, object required

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Why didn't it work? What error or unexpected behaviour did you get?

Comment: how the correct code should be?

Comment: *"how the correct code should be?"* That doesn't look like an error. If you *are* getting a prompt like that, it's coming from your own code that you've omitted from your post.

Comment: how to input text/value to 'User ID=' and 'Password=' from userform?

Comment: At what point does that error occur, I'm *guessing* at `Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection`?

Answer (score 2):

You need single quotes around the strings like this:

```
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=172.20.20.20;Initial Catalog=bank;User ID='" & txtUser.Text & "';Password='" & txtPass.Text & "';"
```

Comment: That's not necessary. Quoting is only needed if the username or passwords themselves contains quotes

Answer (score 0):

> run time error, object required

You are getting that error because your code cannot find `txtUser` and `txtPass`

Ensure the textboxes are there.

[image]

Use `Option Explicit` on the top of your code and then you will notice that it will highlight `txtUser` and say that `Variable not defined`. Of Course you will have to also define cnn as `Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection`

[image]